# Appium Android test - location problems

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I want to test an android app with appium. The app is using Google Maps to show the current location. It's important for the app, that it starts directly at a certain location, otherwise it blocks and gives a message, that the app isn't available at the current location.

Even if I set the location with Appium directly after starting the app, the app blocks as I explained previously. The location is set properly in the current location, but I guess the Google Maps cache is resetted (or something like that) and it starts at a wrong location.

When I test the app manually in the same emulator, I can open the app and it works without problems. The Google Maps shows directly the location that I set. This problem only occurs when the app is started with Appium.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Without Appium server logs it is unclear if service succeed to change location.
Make sure you are setting location [correctly](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriverTest.java#L92):

```
driver.setLocation(location);
```

where location is instance of [Location](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/Location.html)(double latitude, double longitude, double altitude)

In addition, you may try to toggle location on/off before actually setting value:

```
driver.toggleLocationServices();
```